# Returning null for a nullable enum not allowed

Tags: c#, generics, enums, nullable

I've written a simple extension method to help parse a string to a nullable enum type.

```cs
public static TEnum? ParseNullableEnum<TEnum>(this string? str)
    where TEnum : Enum
{
    if (str is null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (!Enum.TryParse(typeof(TEnum), str, ignoreCase: true, out var source))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(str), str, null);
    }

    return (TEnum)source;
}
```

As you can see, the return type is `TEnum?`, where `TEnum` is an `Enum`. And nullable is enabled, so null is a valid value. However, I'm getting an error on line `return null;`

> CS0403: Cannot convert null to type parameter 'TEnum' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using default('TEnum') instead.

Is this a VS bug, or am I doing something wrong? I'm not converting to `TEnum`, the output type is `TEnum?`... right?

Comment: enums are value types, so can't be null , you need at least set e.g `none` constant

Comment: @Turbot but `System.Enum` is _not_ a value type.

Comment: @Turbot `TEnum?` is the return type. it's a nullable enum, like I say in the description. And there's something like [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). (Even though enum is not a value type).

Comment: Can the downvoter _please_ clarify why he/she/they voted down and what can be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
public static TEnum? ParseNullableEnum<TEnum>(this string? str)
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
```

The problem you have is that the `Enum` constraint can match any specific enum type, or the `Enum` class itself. (`Enum` is a weird one: it's the base type of all enum types, but is itself a reference type. It basically represents a boxed enum type, i.e. you can write `Enum foo = condition ? ConsoleColor.Black : ConsoleKey.A;`, to pick on two random different enum types).

In other words, someone could call:

```
ParseNullableEnum<Enum>("thing")
```

Adding the `struct` constraint forces someone to actually pass a specific enum type, rather than `Enum`.

The other part of the puzzle is that if a generic type parameter `T` is not constrained to `class` or `struct`, then `T?` means that `T` is "defaultable" rather than "nullable". This means that:

- If `T` is a reference type, `T?` allows `null` to be assigned
- If `T` is a value type, `T?` **does not** mean `Nullable<T>`, it just means the same as `T`.

This is due to a difference in how `T?` is implemented for reference and value types by the compiler. For a value type, `T?` is shorthand for the type `Nullable<T>`, but for reference types `T?` compiles to the same thing as `T` but has an effect on compiler warnings only. It's not possible for the compiler to emit a method where the return type is `T` when `T` is a reference type, but `Nullable<T>` when `T` is a value type.

So, by not constraining `T` to a reference or value type, your return type of `TEnum?` did not mean `Nullable<TEnum>`, it just meant `TEnum` with different nullable warnings. By constraining `TEnum` to a value type, the compiler is allowed to emit a method which actually returns `Nullable<TEnum>`, and so is allowed to have the value `null`.

Comment: @JHBonarius [FYI](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs#L23)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama thx. I hate that. just specifying `Enum` _should_ be enough IMHO.

Comment: Me too! I couldn't agree more. I imagine there's a reason for it, though I've never taken the time to look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive clarification. I though I understood the new universal nullable syntax, but it's more complex than I though.

Comment: It's worth giving ECMA-335 a read, particularly in this area. The runtime deals with reference and value types in a slightly different way to C#. You accept that you're allowed to do `object foo = Color.Black` or `object bar = 3` to box a value type, because `object` is the superclass of all types, even though `object` is a reference type and `Color`/`int` are value types. It's the same thing here: `Enum` is the supertype of all enum types, even though it's a reference type. `ValueType` is the supertype of all structs, even though it's a reference type.

Comment: Enums actually all inherit from `System.Enum`, which inherits from `Object`. All structs inherit from `System.ValueType`, which inherits from `object`. You can do `ValueType bar = 3` and `Enum foo = Color.Black` for exactly the same reason that you can do `object bar = 3` and `object foo = Color.Black`

Comment: @canton7 Arguably you should have been able to specify `Boxed<SomeStruct>` as an actual type, and that would be a reference type. Then `Enum` would mean an unboxed enum, and `Boxed<Enum>` would mean a boxed one. Equally it might have been wiser had they made enums of different sizes (32/64 bit etc) inherit from different base classes.

Comment: @Charlieface Give ECMA-335 a read. `Boxed<SomeStruct>` doesn't make sense -- you box a value type so that you can refer to it using a variable whose type is a supertype of the value type, e.g. a variable of type `object` can refer to any boxed value type. A variable of type `Boxed<SomeStruct>` can only refer to a boxed `SomeStruct`. `Enum` referring to an unboxed enum also doesn't make sense. Enums have different sizes, and you can't have a variable whose type is a value type refer to values which are different shapes

Comment: @canton7 I've read ECMA-335 many times. The fact that `Boxed<SomeStruct>` can only refer to `Boxed<SomeStruct>` is immaterial, so is true of any `sealed` class. It makes a difference when you want to treat a struct as a reference type, and you currently need to hack it with a weird `Tuple<T1>`. And it matters more when you want to use generics, when there is a `class` constraint on the type parameter.

Comment: @Charlieface Why not just use `object` in that case? I don't think I've ever needed a `Boxed<T>`, or had a case where that would be useful. It certainly can't replace boxing to `object`. Plus, you can always write your own.

Comment: @canton7 Because then you lose type information and need to cast every time you use it. You're right, I could write my own, but there's already `Tuple<T1>` it doesn't get out of the fact you need to constantly do `x.Value`. What I'm saying is that a boxed struct should be declarable as an actual type, and such a variable would *be* that type with reference sematics, rather than having to contain it inside something else. It does occasionally have uses otherwise `Tuple<T1>` would never have existed. https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fruntime+%2F+Tuple%3C%5B%5E%2C%5D%2B%3E+%2F&type=code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if (str is null)
    {
        return default(TEnum?);
    }
```

*You should specify the type(s) for which it can be null. All different types can be null, so you need to specify them*

Comment: which would be the same as `default`. But I don't want to write `default` as it's not explicit enough. It could be confusing if the default value of `TEnum` is used or `null` is used. I want to explicitly set `null`.